# Odoo 8 Many2many ProgrammingError: Error: relation « _unknown » does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8

I've create a model which inherits `stock.picking` (from `stock` module) in a custom module (`stock_bt`).
Purchase module depends on `stock_bt` module (I've added `stock_bt` to dependencies in the `purchase` module's  `__openerp__.py` file).

Now I want to add a `Many2many` relation between `purchase.requisition` and `stock.picking` in `stock.picking` but I am getting this error:

```
ProgrammingError: Error:  relation « _unknown » does not exist
```

Need your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please paste your code in your question what you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

One:  This kind of error happen when you miss spell the model name, in odoo use always copy and past.

Two: if you define a `many2one` or `many2many` relation you should mention the `module` that contains the `co_model` in `depends` in the `__openerp__.py`.

```
 depends : ['stock',.....]
```

Comment: Thank you @Cherif Odoo. I was in the situation two, but the strange fact is with `Many2one` it works without any error, the error occurs when i try to add a `Many2many`. Anyway I've been able to solve the problem by creating a inheritance of the stock.picking model in the purchase module, because otherwise I'll have a circular dependency issue.

Comment: up vote at least ... if you have sircular dependency your need to change your modules to prevent that and define witch module is installed first.